Differences between UniswapV2 swapExactTokensForTokens and swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens
Having issues swapping tokens with Fees.  I've tried both swapExactTokensForTokens and swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens.  I am forking Mainnet using hardhat for testing. What is going wrong?
The code below works great for WETH > Token and Token > WETH when there is no fee.
   // NOTE: MAX_INT used for testing only!
   IERC20(_token).approve(address(params.router), MAX_INT);
        
   // TOKEN > WETH
   // FLIP the paths for WETH > TOKEN
   address[] memory path = new address[](2);
   path[0] = _token;
   path[1] = WETH_ADDRESS;

   uint256[] memory amountsOut = IUniswapV2Router02(params.router).getAmountsOut(_amountIn, path);
   IUniswapV2Router02(params.router).swapExactTokensForTokens(_amountIn, amountsOut[1], path, address(this), deadline);

When I use swapExactTokensForTokens ONLY when the path is WETH > TOKEN, do I get transaction errors.
reverted with reason string 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED' when using both swapExactTokensForTokens and swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens.
So three part question:

How can you determine that a token/pair has a fee associated with it and how much for buy/sell?
If the token is unsaleable, meaning I can buy it, but I can't sell it, is that error (TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED) typical for that situation?
If the token has low sell or buy limits, would you get this error (TRANSFER_FORM_FAILED)?  If so, how can you determine the sell/buy limit of this token?

Thanks for the help!
